# My texture is backwards?

Tags: modeling, texturing, light

Okay, my texture isn't backwards as in it has been reversed or flipped. But rather if I were to make a sun light object facing it's direction it would not appear, it's only black. But if I were to face the sun in the opposite direction, it would appear as it should, although everything is else dark.

Pictures

[image: Sun light object is backwards]

[image: Sun light object is forwards]

Any ideas? Help would be very much appreciative!

Comment: You probably have either inverted normals or negatively scaled objects

Comment: Select all the faces A twice and press ctrl+N